# Excel Right Click - Lost Right click option "Assign Macro" on Buttons

Tags: excel

I have lost the menu Option "Assign Macro..." on the native right click options in Excel.

This is not about creating a custom right click menu..   my options are :

Cut 
 Copy 
 
 Paste 
 Edit Text 
 Grouping -> 
 Order -> 
 Format Control

It is very annoying as I cannot trace what Sub will be called from clicking the button!

Comment: Are you sure your button is a Form control button and not ActiveX?

Comment: I am aware of the differences.   In fact as I work in a team my colleagues can open the same Workbook and Right click but my menu option is not available.   So I *KNOW* that it is not the type of button.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the original button and replace it with the shape. Then you will be able assign the macro.